# Iterating out the elements in a nested tuple one by one

Tags: python, tuples

I have a task that requires me to return a given tuple, but by creating it as a new tuple. Hence, my code is as follows.

```
def new_tup(tree):
    if tree == ():
        return tree
    else:
        return tree[0] + new_tup(tree[1:])
```

However, how should I amend this code if I want to concatenate elements within a nested tuple into this new tuple? Currently, the code only works if the elements within the tuple are just elements, but not if there is a tuple nested within the tuple.

Comment: Please give input and output sample.

Comment: This code actually doesn't work at all despite your claim because `new_tup[1:]` makes no sense.

Comment: Sry, I actually retyped it out so I made a slight mistake. However, my problem remains. For instance, (1,2,3,4,5) would work because my function concatenates together nicely, but (1,2,(3,4),5) would not because it treats the (3,4) as one element and adds the element in. However, I want the function to add it in separately.

Answer (score 0):

To collaps an array (or tuple of tuples) into one dimension, you could use a function like [numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) after [converting to a ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).

However if you are looking for a short function to do it yourself, you can try something like this:

```
input = ((1,2),3,4,(5,6,(7,8)),9,(10))

def flatten(a):
    result = []
    try:
        for i in a:
            result.extend(flatten(i))
    except TypeError:
        result = [a]
    return tuple(result)

print(flatten(input))
```